# How to run a CSS animation only once every hour (for landing page)?

Tags: javascript, css

I created a landing page for my website. The animation repeats whenever the user reloads or comes back to the landing page. This will be quite distracting for the user. Hence, I tried to write the JavaScript codes that limits the animation to run only once every hour. However, it is not working. Can we achieve this using JavaScript?

```js
function runAnimation() {
  const lastAnimatedAt = localStorage.getItem('lastAnimatedAt');

  if (lastAnimatedAt) {
    const lastAnimationTime = new Date(lastAnimatedAt);
    const currentTime = new Date();

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds between the current time and the last animation time
    const timeDifference = currentTime - lastAnimationTime;

    // Check if less than an hour has passed since the last animation
    if (timeDifference < 3600000) {
      return; // Skip animation
    }
  }

  const textElement = document.querySelector('.text');
  const mainElement = document.querySelector('main');

  // Add animation classes to elements
  textElement.classList.add('text-animation');
  mainElement.classList.add('herolanding-animation');


  // Remove animation classes after animations complete
  textElement.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    textElement.classList.remove('text-animation');
  }, {
    once: true
  });


  mainElement.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    mainElement.classList.remove('herolanding-animation');
  }, {
    once: true
  });



  // Store current time in localStorage after animations complete
  localStorage.setItem('lastAnimatedAt', new Date().toISOString());
}

// Run the animations immediately
runAnimation();

// Set the interval to run the animations every hour

setInterval(runAnimation, 3600000); // 3600000 milliseconds = 1 hour
```

```css
.text {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  animation: herot 1s forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  z-index: 1000;
}

@keyframes herot {
  0% {
    font-size: 15rem;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes herolanding {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

main {
  animation-name: herolanding;
  animation-duration: 1.1s;
  transition: ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <a> Hello </a>
</div>

<main class="text2">
  <a>body</aa>
    </main>
```

Comment: If you want to persist it over a page reload, you'll need to save something in localStorage. Currenty, you're just restarting the animation after an hour.

Comment: In your runAnimations function add in if statement that wraps the entire thing `if (!localStorage.getItem("animated")) {` and at the bottom of the if statement `localStorage.setItem("animated",1)` that will check if the page hasn't been animated and save saying it has

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` doesn't persist its state if you refresh your page, navigate to another route (unless your app is an SPA), close the tab, or close the browser.

So, in order to persist the countdown of the 1 hour non-animation, you need to store that state in `localStorage` or browser cookie, etc.

My suggestion is to store the last animated time on user's browser's `localStorage` and before running the animation, first check that value and decide whether to run the animation or not.

Here's the pseudo-code using `localStorage`:

```
function runAnimation() {
  const lastAnimatedAt = localStorage.getItem('lastAnimatedAt');

  if (lastAnimatedAt) {
    if (/* lastAnimatedAt was within last hour */) return;
  }

  // do animation
  // ...
  
  localStorage.setItem('lastAnimatedAt', /* current time in ISO string */);
}
```

Obviously, you can also improve your logic by adding `setInterval` just for the case the user opens the homepage and stays there for a long time.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my code as per your suggestion but its still not working

Comment: What's happening? Can you share the code?

Comment: The animation is running without any delay. How the animation in my code works is- it runs immediately after the webpage loads and it's the first thing the user sees. Even though I included the JavaScript, the animation is running whenever I reload the page or come back to the home page after visiting other pages.

Comment: That means your condition in `if (/* lastAnimatedAt was within last hour */) return;` is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think that best way to orchestrate it could be to use animation with **duration matching your desired period** and only progressively enhance it with `animation-delay` to align its first occurrence with some fixed point in the future.

Example scaled down to single minute period:

```js
const w = 60 - (new Date).getSeconds();
document.write(
  `Wait ${w} seconds for the first run.`
);
document.body.style.setProperty(
  '--secondsToNextWholeMinute',
  w
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--secondsToNextWholeMinute, 0) * 1s);
  animation-name: a;
}

@keyframes a {
  1% {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
  0%,
  2% {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
Animation runs each minute.
```

With this you'll get guaranteed period without necessity of client-side persistence nor JavaScript intervals.

The second (fallback) value for the `--secondsToNextWholeMinute` custom property can be used for cases client-side JavaScript does not run: `0` would mean the animation will run immediately after each reload and then in minute intervals from that point onwards.

JS progressively enhances that delay to be shifted to whole user's wall clock minute (in our case).

Perhaps the trickiest part of this approach will be setting percentage fractions of the long 1h period to match seconds: `1s` should be `0.0277777778%` of one hour.

Comment: Hi, I don’t understand how this works over a reload. Could you explain?

Comment: Let's say you load the page at 9:06:45. JS computes that there are 15 seconds to next whole minute (9:07:00) and sets this exact 15s  delay to the animation, so you see it at 9:07. If you reload the page after that and it loads at, say, 9:07:15, then the delay to next whole minute will be 45 seconds, and so on. Is it more clear?

Comment: yes, thanks. So all that is being 'sacrificed' is the gap between showing it on the first load (which wont happen) and, say, the on-the-hour setting. So for a long gap period a user is unlikely to see it at all - I guess only OP can say whether that is acceptable or not.